# How To Associate Rails Model Records With Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

If I have a Rails model for something like Quests (like in a game) I'd have attributes like name, description, ect. but I'd also need some code associated with each quest to determine if the requirements have been met by a player to complete the quest.

What is the best way to associate some code with records from a model?  Should I make a quest_function attribute in the model and write a function for each record in the models/quest.rb file when I create a new quest?  This seems clunky and error prone.

How should something like this be done in Rails?

Comment: Is the idea that each quest has potentially different completion criteria

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you have several options.

The first, like you said, is to store a method/function name in your record and then call that method whenever you need to evaluate whether that Quest for that record has been completed. In rough code:

```
class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :quest_method

    def completed?
      self.send(quest_method)
    end

    def end_quest
       Monster.find_by_name('FINAL BOSS').dead?
    end
end

Quest.create name: 'End Quest', quest_method: 'end_quest'
```

This isn't quite as bad as you think. This is essentially how [single table inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) works, but instead of storing a method name it stores the class name in the `type` column.

```
class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base

    def finished?
        # default value, or throw an error
        false
    end

end

class EndQuest < Quest

    def finished?
        Monster.find_by_name('END BOSS').dead?
    end
end

EndQuest.create # have to do this for all quests
```

In either case, you're writing the behavior as code, and just storing a reference to the desired behavior in your record. You *do* have to create all the records by hand with the proper types or method names and make sure everything stays in sync. But at least with single-table inheritance ActiveRecord takes care of some of that.

There's nothing stopping you, however, from storing code itself into the database.

```
class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base

    attr_accessible :name, :completed_expr

    def completed?
        eval(completed_expr)
    end

end

Quest.create name: 'END QUEST', 
  completed_expr: "Monster.find_by_name('BIG BOSS').dead?"
```

This, of course is potentially dangerous and error prone unless you know exactly what you're doing—but it does give you complete flexibility to rewrite the quest completion criteria at run-time.

Finally, if you want the most sophistication and complexity, you might want to look at using a rules engine (or, rolling out your own complete with DSL) to encompass your business (game world) rules and store that.

```
class Quest < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name, :completion_rule

    def completed?
        RulesEngine.evaluate(completion_rule)
    end
end

Quest.create name: 'END QUEST', 
  completion_rule: "Monster(name: 'BIG BOSS', state: 'dead')"
```

The main advantage is by storing your quest-specific behavior or rule in a DSL (which is *not* raw Ruby code) you get some level of security—you can't just accidentally `eval` malicious or errant code and bring the house down.

You can also gain some efficiency if your production rules are modeled in such a way where you can use something like the [Rete algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rete_algorithm) to evaluate them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a function whenever a **quest** is created then you should use rails callbacks like **after_create** or **after_update**.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview